# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'url')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my code which is `item.jsx` and this is indicating all my items that will be set out onto a grid for an ecommerce.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { IconButton, Box, Typography, useTheme, Button } from "@mui/material";
import AddIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Add";
import RemoveIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Remove";
import { shades } from "../theme";
import { addToCart } from "../state";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Item = ({ item, width }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);
  const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);
  const {
    palette: { neutral },
  } = useTheme();

  const { category, price, name, image } = item.attributes;
  const {
    data: {
      attributes: {
        formats: {
          medium: { url }, // <-- issue here
        },
      },
    },
  } = image;

  return (
    <Box width={width}>
      <Box
        position="relative"
        onMouseOver={() => setIsHovered(true)}
        onMouseOut={() => setIsHovered(false)}
      >
        <img
          alt={item.name}
          width="300px"
          height="400px"
          src={`http://localhost:1337${url}`}
          onClick={() => navigate(`/item/${item.id}`)}
          style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
        />
        <Box
          display={isHovered ? "blocked" : "none"}
          position="absolute"
          bottom="10%"
          left="0"
          width="100%"
          padding="0 5%"
        >
          <Box display="flex" justifyContent="space-between">
            {/* AMOUNT */}
            <Box
              display="flex"
              alignItems="center"
              backgroundColor={shades.neutral[100]}
              borderRadius="3px"
            >
              <IconButton onClick={() => setCount(Math.max(count - 1, 1))}>
                <RemoveIcon />
              </IconButton>
              <Typography color={shades.primary[300]}>{count}</Typography>
              <IconButton onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
                <AddIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </Box>

            {/* BUTTON */}
            <Button
              onClick={() => {
                dispatch(addToCart({ item: { ...item, count } }));
              }}
              sx={{ backgroundColor: shades.primary[300], color: "white" }}
            >
              Add to Cart
            </Button>
          </Box>
        </Box>
      </Box>

      <Box mt="3px">
        <Typography variant="subtitle2" color={neutral.dark}>
          {category
            .replace(/([A-Z])/g, "$1 ")
            .replace(/^./, (str) => str.toUpperCase())}
        </Typography>
        <Typography>{name}</Typography>
        <Typography fontWeight="bold">${price}</Typography>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default Item;
```

It keeps coming up with "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'url')". I have indicated where in the code so that you can see what is apparently "undefined".

Comment: the three hashes outlines the code its saying is wrong

Comment: Have you checked what the `image` object looks like, since there is no `url` property, maybe a typo?

Comment: Where do you think `url` in `{ url }` comes from?

Comment: and im new to react js so please bear with me

Comment: does `image` have `.data.attributes.formats.medium` property. It probably has `.data.attributes.formats` but that does not have `medium` property - if I'm reading the error correctly

Comment: idk jaromanda have no clue lol thats why im on here

Comment: It seems that `item.attributes.image.data.attributes.formats` is defined since there's no issue accessing the properties up to this point. The error is, however, informing you that `item.attributes.image.data.attributes.formats.medium` is undefined which the error is thrown when attempting to then access `item.attributes.image.data.attributes.formats.medium.url`. Check this `item` prop that is passed. Can you [edit] to include a more complete [mcve]?

Comment: @sylo, @Jaromanda is right, the `image` is missing the `.data.attributes.formats.medium` property. Double check that you pass it down to the `<Item>` component.